# GaussianBlur that fit the whole image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have to filter high frequencies from the input image and I know that Gaussian filter is good in this task. First I transform my image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft2, ifft2, fftshift, ifftshift
...
image = fftshift(fft2(image))
image_real = image.real
image_imag = image.imag
```

get the shape of image, blur it and combine

```
x, y = image.shape
image_real_filter = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_real, (x, y), 0)
image_imag_filter = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_imag, (x, y), 0)
image = image_real_filter + 1j * image_imag_filter
```

And transform it back.

```
image = ifft2(ifftshift(image))
```

It should filter high frequencies but it doesn't I get the black image.

Comment: What happens if you try a non-zero sigma for the gaussian blur?

Comment: I get a black image